# Content inside menu flashes just while reloading/refreshing page

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I was trying to implement a megamenu, using this plugin, https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Mega-Menu-dmenu/demo/xmpl1.html

I successfully implemented it, only issue is the entire content is displaying just before the page finishes to refresh/reloads. I tried placing the Js file on head & footer, after Jquery file, inside document ready, nothing really helped.

https://jsfiddle.net/mdsebans/s2quywj5/6/

```
            <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $(window).resize();
    });
    $('#menu').dmenu({
        menu: {
            logo: true,
            align: 'right'
        },
        item: {
            bg: true,
            border: false,
            subindicator: true,

            fit: [{
                items: null,
                fitter: 'icon-hide',
                order: 'all'
            }, {
                items: null,
                fitter: 'icon-only',
                order: 'all'
            }, {
                items: ':not(.dm-item_align-right)',
                fitter: 'submenu',
                order: 'rtl'
            }, {
                items: ':not(.dm-item_align-right)',
                fitter: 'hide',
                order: 'rtl'
            }]
        },
        submenu: {
            arrow: false,
            border: false,
            shadow: true
        },
        subitem: {
            bg: true,
            border: false
        }

    });
});
```

Don't want the content inside dropdown to be displayed on each click on menu items or reload of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loader for hiding HTML data to show users.

When browser render the page it first renders the HTML content

[See Here](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-browser-rendering-works-behind-the-scenes-6782b0e8fb10/)

So you can use the following code :- 
End Of the HTML file add this link

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

On the CSS file

```
.loader{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#fff;
  }
```

In JQuery you can add this line to hide

```
$(function() {
       $(window).resize();
       $(".loader").hide();
   });
```

I think this will help.

Comment: If this answer helpfull Please rate up